# PHP code broken into external file as include

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I have a snippet of code that works fine. But this code has some login credentials (connecting to remote server) in it. So instead of typing the login details on each page, I would like to include the details to another include file. When I do this, i include('filename.php') in the new script and for some reason that does not work. I get the following error: 
Fatal error: Class 'Bigcommerce\Api\Client' not found in

The include file I created looks like this:

```
require_once ('../bigcommerce.php');

use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
        'store_url' => 'https://www.website.com',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'api_key'   => 'api_key'
));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);
```

The code file that has the code above as an include is:

```
<?php 

include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
        echo ("<br />");
}

?>
```

This is the complete block of code that works in a single file:

```
<?php

require ('bigcommerce.php');
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
        'store_url' => 'https://www.website.com',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'api_key'   => 'api_key'
));

Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts();

foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
        echo ("<br />");
}
?>
```

How do I put this code in an external file so that I can include it throughout my site?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: There is no indication of yourself using the class 'ABC'. Are you sure that is the error? `require` isn't a function; it's a language construct, so you shouldn't use it like one.

Comment: the problem might be with file path, always use `include_once 'file.php'` if you don't want your file to be re-included further in script.

Comment: What's in `../bigcommerce.php`?

Comment: Where are your namespaces? The command `use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;` implies that you are using namespaces, but your code above doesn't show any uses of `namespace`.

Comment: Now that you are using a php include, make sure your file paths are being called correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can I define an object in the include and access it in the file that is calling the include, test.php? As soon as I put $products = Bigcommerce::getProducts(); into my test.php the code breaks. Thanks again!

Comment: I resolved the issue. I just had to add use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce; in both files.Thanks all for the help!